# How to disable pylint warnings and messages on Visual Studio Code?

Tags: python, pylint, pylintrc

I am using a Mac and programming with Python on VS Code. After installing pylint, I had a bunch of warnings and messages. How do I disable these? I know about adding some lines to the pylintrc file, but I don't know where to find it or how to create it on a Mac.

Comment: If you type (the title of) your question into google it gives you the answer in the first result

Comment: For a single file, just use `# pylint: disable=all`

Answer (score 27, accepted):

**Fully disable the linting**

Here is a link that explain how to do it : [Disable Linting on VsCode](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/linting#_disable-linting).

To do so, type `Command + Shift + P` (or `Ctrl + Shift + P` on PC) in VsCode. This will open a command prompt at the top of the window. Then type the command `Python: Enable Linting`, and select `off`.

Another option is to choose no linter. To do so, open the command prompt with `Command + Shift + P` (or `Ctrl + Shift + P` on PC), type `Python: Select Linter`, and choose the option `Disable Linting`.

---

**Disable warnings, but keep errors :**

If you want to keep the errors, but disable only the warnings, you can also configure pylint directly from VsCode. Go to the menu `File ->  Preferences -> Settings` (Or open directly with `Command + ,` or `Ctrl + ,`). Then in the search box at the top of the window, search for `pylint Args`. Click on the button `Add item` and add the line `--disable=W`.

[image]

Comment: To disable a specific warning/info, mention its exact name. For eg) `--disable=bad-indentation` or `--disable=logging-fstring-interpolation`

Comment: Tested right now : doesn't work with Python 3.8.10 and Version: 1.73.1 (system setup) // Commit: 6261075646f055b99068d3688932416f2346dd3b // Date: 2022-11-09T04:27:29.066Z // Electron: 19.0.17 // Chromium: 102.0.5005.167 // Node.js: 16.14.2 // V8: 10.2.154.15-electron.0 // OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.22621 // Sandboxed: No

Comment: Pricise python version = Python 3.8.10 (tags/v3.8.10:3d8993a, May  3 2021, 11:48:03) [MSC v.1928 64 bit (AMD64)]

Comment: Entirely disabling linting surely would disable pylint, but it will disable other linters as well.

Answer (score 6):

I had disabled pylint in the settings but was still getting pylint linting showing up in my code, until I noticed there was a "pylint" vscode extension installed. Disabling that extension finally silenced pylint!