# How to show just the pylint errors and hide the infos and warnings VS Code?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pylint

I am trying to see **only the pylint errors**, but I am getting a lot of info-level messages instead, that doesn't matter at all (at least to me). The real problem is that it shows all of this non-critical info while the real critical errors are "hidden".

Here is a sample:

[image: screenshot of Problems tab with all the pylint problems]

Here is my current **setting.json** in VS Code:

```
{
    "python.linting.pylintEnabled": true,
    "python.linting.enabled": true,
}
```

Comment: "*only **critical** errors and warnings*" The issues are differentiated into levels (such as info, warning, and error) and into codes (such as W0109, E1101, etc.). See (see http://pylint-messages.wikidot.com/all-codes). There is no clear-cut setting to say "only show **critical** errors and warnings". You'll have to determine which ones are critical _for you_, then disable all but errors, and/or disable specific codes (ex. `--disable=W0142`).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to disable pylint warnings and messages on VS Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63809051/2745495)

Comment: Wait. How can I add that flag? `--disable=W0142`

Comment: Please check the links I posted in my previous comments. The answers there already describe how.

Comment: @GinoMempin please consider to add a similar answer like I posted to mark your answer as the correct one. Thanks.

Comment: @GinoMempin I can't find the code for  `Using an f-string that does not have any interpolated variables`. Any advice?

Comment: Thanks for the offer, but similar to maintaining a codebase, since there is already an answer somewhere else that perfectly answers your question, I'd rather link to that instead and close this as a duplicate. Better to maintain the answer in 1 place.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Gino Mempin to me the solution is like:

```
{
    "python.linting.pylintEnabled": true,
    "python.linting.enabled": true,
    "python.linting.pylintArgs": [
        "--disable=C0116,C0301,C0303,C0325,W0311,W1202,W1201,W1203,W1309,W0702,C0103,C0415"
    ]
}
```

Where `--disable=XXXX` can be found in official docs: https://docs.pylint.org/en/latest/technical_reference/features.html