# How to disable ALL linting / annotations /error handling in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code

I only want to use VSCode as a syntax highlighter. I don't want any linting, annotations, error handling, or anything besides for syntax highlighting, for any languages. I've been looking all over but I can't find a setting for this.

Comment: You will probably need to adjust the settings on a per-language basis.  So a possible answer to your question could be lengthy - you may want to include a handful of languages you specifically want to know about.

Comment: @TimothyG. Hi thanks. too bad I was just hoping for some kind of "all in one", disable ALL features, bug checking, annotations, squiggly lines etc., everything, except for syntax high lighting. I guess its a no?

Comment: Most programming languages have their own extension that controls settings like this, hence my previous comment. For example, [here is a post about disabling linting for Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63809051/how-to-disable-pylint-warnings-and-messages-on-visual-studio-code) which uses Pylint. So generally, yes, its probably going to be a per-programming language basis.